# Html embedded images showned as attachment in email

Tags: blackberry, email-client, email-templates

I have created an email template using Outlook 2013. In this template I have some images hosted on the web.
When i send the mail everything is seen Ok on the various Outlook version. But when the mail is seen on the Blackberry My mail seems ok but at the end of the mail, the images are also listed as attachments. So I see the correct template and the list of images. How can i prevent this behaviour? I need to keep the same behaviour as in the Outlook version (not display the listing of the images as attachments at the end of the mail)
Could you point me in the right direction?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to prevent Outlook from sending images as MIME attachments. Other Outlooks will interpret them correctly, whereas most email clients will see them at attachments.